# Errors while bringing up the sample network hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Getting the following error :-

> Error: got unexpected status: FORBIDDEN -- Failed to reach implicit
>   threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining : permission denied

Comment: CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
+ peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
+ res=1
+ set +x
2018-03-30 03:56:32.930 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: got unexpected status: FORBIDDEN -- Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining: permission denied

Comment: Can anyone please help here? I couldn't bring up the first network. I am using the v1.1 and followed the https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/getting_started.html documentation

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error after I had previously brought up my network and forgot to kill all the channels.

Try running:

```
./byfn.sh -m down
```

Then start over and see if it works.